# Label text overlapping in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So I am calling an update function in a `GridLayout` which has 3 `cols` and a picture in the first, a `Label` in the second and a button in the third row. At the start of the function I clear all the children and then recreate all the children in a for loop. On the first call of the function the labels get displayed correctly. But on the second and every following call each label has two texts overlapping somehow except the first one. I really don't get how this can happen... I'll attach two pictures describing my problem on the first and every following call of the Function.

How it looks like after the first call:
[image]

How it looks like on following calls:
[image]

Here's my code:

```py
class SelfMadePlans(Screen):
    name = "selfmadeplans"

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SelfMadePlans, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.scrl_view_2 = ScrollView(
            size_hint_y=.9,
            pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0},
            do_scroll_x=False,
            do_scroll_y=True,
            size_hint_x=1
        )

        self.scrl_child_2 = GridLayout(
            size_hint_x=1,
            size_hint_y=None,
            cols=3,
            height=20000,
            row_default_height=150,
            row_force_default=True,
        )

        self.add_widget(self.scrl_view_2)
        self.scrl_view_2.add_widget(self.scrl_child_2)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.innit, 1)

    def innit(self,dt):
        self.add_widget(self.manager.get_screen("navigationdrawer"))

    def update(self):
        self.current_selfmade_plan = MDApp.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("currentselfmadeplans")

        self.scrl_child_2.children.clear()

        for file in makeplans.plan_details:
            print("file in plandetails: " + str(file))

            print("file in dict: " + str(makeplans.plan_details[file]))
            img_path = main.training_plans_path + "/" + file + ".png"

            img = Image(
                source=img_path
            )

            lbl = Label(
                text=file,
                color="black",
                size_hint = (.5, .15)
            )

            btn = Button(
                text="Show",
                on_release=lambda x, pth=file: self.current_selfmade_plan.show_selfmade_plan(pth),
            )

            self.scrl_child_2.add_widget(img)
            self.scrl_child_2.add_widget(lbl)
            self.scrl_child_2.add_widget(btn)
```

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: maybe you should create labels in `__init__`  and in update replace text in existing labels. OR you should keep information if label exists (ie. `self.exists = False`) and later: create labels if they don't exist (`if not self.exists: ...`), and replace text if they exist  (`if self.exists: ...`).

Comment: better create minimal working code with example data in code - so we could simply copy and test it.

Comment: Try using `self.scrl_child_2.clear_widgets()` instead of `self.scrl_child_2.children.clear()`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Ah well i don't know how i didn't realise this because i have used it multiple times before but somehow changed it in this part of code... Thank you so much!